# PHP file not displaying correctly (Code showing ONLY for this file)

Tags: php

PHP is displaying correctly for all other php files, but this file is unique. It creates an rss feed for nfl scores. When I view it all I see is code. I believe I must be missing a certain module from Apache2 or something, but I am coming up blank. Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code. This code works great on my personal hostgator web server account as is, which is what leads me to believe that it is a problem with my apache2 configuration on our local server. I have tried it on three different apache2 servers with the same problem.

```
<?
function get_content($url)
{
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

   ob_start();

   curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
   $string = ob_get_contents();

   ob_end_clean();

   return $string;
}

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\n\n";
echo "<!DOCTYPE rss PUBLIC \"-//Netscape Communications//DTD RSS 0.91//EN\"\n";
echo " \"http://my.netscape.com/publish/formats/rss-0.91.dtd\">\n\n";
echo "<rss version=\"0.91\">\n\n";
echo "<channel>\n";

echo "<title>NFL Scores</title>\n";
echo "<link>http://www.nfl.com/</link>\n";
echo "<description>NFL Scores</description>\n";
echo "<language>en-us</language>\n";
echo "<image>\n";
echo " <title>NFL Scores</title>\n";
echo " <url>http://www.mpiii.com/scores/nfl.gif</url>\n";
echo " <link>http://www.nfl.com</link>\n";
echo "</image>\n";
echo "<webMaster>info@nfl.com</webMaster>\n";

$content = get_content ("http://sports.espn.go.com/nfl/bottomline/scores");

$content_array=explode("&", $content);
$scorearray = array();
$i=0;
foreach($content_array as $content) {
        if (strpos($content, "_left")) {
                $equalpos = strpos($content, "=");
                $end = strlen($content);
                $title = substr($content, ($equalpos+1), $end);
                $title = str_replace("^", "", $title);
                $title = str_replace("%20", " ", $title);
                $title = ucwords(str_replace("END OF 4TH", "Final", $title));
                $title = str_replace('( ', '(', ucwords(str_replace('(', '( ', $title)));
                $title = str_replace("FINAL", "Final", $title);
                $scorearray[$i]["title"] = $title;

        }
        if (strpos($content, "_url")) {
                $equalpos = strpos($content, "=");
                $end = strlen($content);
                $url = substr($content, ($equalpos+1), $end);
                $url = str_replace("^", "", $url);
                $url = str_replace("%20", " ", $url);
                $scorearray[$i]["url"] = $url;
                                $i++;

        }
}
foreach($scorearray as $score) {
        echo "<item>\n";
        echo "<title>".$score["title"]."</title>\n";
        echo "<link>".$score["url"]."</link>\n";
        echo "</item>\n";
}

echo "</channel>\n";
echo "</rss>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `short_open_tag` enabled?

Comment: Try replacing `<?` with `<?php`.

Comment: The [documentations](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) say it's on by default.

Comment: @Shahar Who said the OP was using a default configuration on his server? `short_open_tags` is one of the most widely disabled features of PHP in production environments.

Comment: I'm using php 5.6.4 and for me this works. Which version are you using?

Comment: Forest for the trees, indeed all it was was the fact that I had not written <?php instead of <?    Can't believe I missed something so simple.  Thanks.

Comment: You could post that as an answer and mark it as accepted. That way, people know, that your question is answered.